# Solr stop words question

Tags: solr

My Solr installation is set up with the default stop words plus a few extra ones that I added.

Once in a while a user types a query string that consists of all stopwords. The result is that solr returns no documents at all.

What I would like to happen instead is that Solr returns all documents. Is this possible?

Frank

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, you could fetch the stopwords in your application (e.g. `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/file/?file=stopwords.txt`), and use that list to detect stopwords in your user query *before* sending the query to Solr. If you detect that they're all stopwords, replace with `*:*` to fetch all documents.